# How to print value from LEFT JOIN through SqlDataReader?

Tags: c#, sql, left-join, sqldatareader

I have created this "ShowSubcategories" method, and its working just fine!

Also i tried to use the build in command "SqlDataReader" This seems to be working just fine,
until i tried using a left join to output the actual category name instead of just the category id in sdr[2].

how am i supposed to use the left join output inside the sqldatareader otherwise then tried here?
sdr["CategoryName"]

```
public static void ShowSubCategories(SqlConnection conn)
{
    string SQL = (@"SELECT SubCategoryID, SubCategoryName, CategoryID, 
                  SubCategoryEmployeeID FROM SubCategories
                  left join Categories on SubCategories.CategoryID=Categories.CategoryID");
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQL, conn);
    SqlDataReader sdr = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (sdr.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-5} {1,-10} {2,-10} {3,-10}", sdr[0], sdr[1], sdr["CategoryName"], sdr[3]);
    }
    sdr.Close();
}
```

Comment: There's no `CategoryName` column in the results to begin with. A DbDataReader is used to read the results returned by the server, it can't modify the query

Comment: Test query in SQL Server Management Studio before trying in C#.  If you have an error in the query SSMS will show the error while c# will not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A query can return only the fields that are present after the SELECT statement.
If *CategoryName* belongs to the table *Categories* then you need to add it to the SELECT statement.

In these situations it is a good practice to create tablenames ALIAS (a short string that represent the name of the table in the query). As you can see the query is more clear and the text is shorter

```
public static void ShowSubCategories(SqlConnection conn)
{
    string SQL = (@"SELECT sc.SubCategoryID, sc.SubCategoryName, sc.CategoryID, 
                           sc.SubCategoryEmployeeID, c.CategoryName 
                    FROM SubCategories sc
                       LEFT JOIN Categories c ON sc.CategoryID=c.CategoryID");
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQL, conn);
    SqlDataReader sdr = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (sdr.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-5} {1,-10} {2,-10} {3,-10}", sdr[0], sdr[1], sdr["CategoryName"], sdr[3]);
    }
    sdr.Close();
}
```

Notice also that you don't need to prefix the name of the field with the alias when you extract values from the DataReader.

Comment: It would be a good idea to make the original code a little better in terms of disposal of resources.